# Is there one method of youtube-api about the copyright summary and status of video?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there some method of youtube api to query the the copyright summary and status of video? When uploading the video to the Youtube channel,  we want to know the copyright summary and status. The info as above:

Answer (score 0):

If you get a video resource there is status.rejectionReason that is the only mention to copyright in the API

[image]

I think it would be nice to have more information on the copyright status of a video .  If you add a Feature request I will add my star to it